# Trailing characters error in a substitution command

Tags: visual-mode, replace, visual-block

Suddenly simple find&replace stopped working in one particular case. I'm selecting the code-block in visual-mode, so the final command looks like:

```
'<,'>%s/someStuff/stuff/gI
```

I get the error:

> Trailing characters

It's very strange behavior because the same commands worked very well earlier.

[Search and replace in VIM results in trailing characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6714469/search-and-replace-in-vim-results-in-trailing-characters) didn't help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You don't need `%`, as you already have another range (`'<,'>`) for your command `s`. So it must be simply `'<,'>s/SomeStuff/stuff/gI`.